# ¿Como puedo relacionar 2 tablas que son (Artist y Genre) en MERN Stack desde backend?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, mongodb

//lo que quiero hacer es que desde el formulario pueda ingresar el Name del Artist y su Genre, que genre con un list group desplegue el nombre de los Genres no sus _id y al selecionar un Genre que guarde su _id respectivo en la base de datos MongoDB junto con el name del Artits

[image: Este es el Modelo de Artist]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta del todo, pero creo podrías agregar el id del artista en "genre" como artist_id y luego pedir los "genre" con ese artist_id

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.